# Can a matrix element be an outer product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, tensor-products, outer-product

Suppose I have a matrix P = \begin{bmatrix}x⊗x&x⊗y\\y⊗x&y⊗y\end{bmatrix} which is equal to another matrix Q = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.

Is it possible to solve for x and y.

Since xy and yx are equal to b and c and are not the same, the elements in the matrix P are outer product of two matrices x and y.

Is it possible to solve for x and y such that xy and yx can be made predictable.

Kindly let me know if I am not clear.

Thank you for the kind help.

Comment: what do you mean by the tensor? Matrices are equal if their elements are equal. In your case $a=x\otimes x , b= x\otimes y, c= y\otimes x, d= y\otimes y$. If by $\otimes$ you mean the usual multiplication, then in order to have a solution you need that $a,d>0$ and that $b=c$ also you need that $bc=ad$ (so zero determinant). In this case $x=\sqrt a$ and $y=\sqrt d$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By ⊗ I mean outer product. Outer product of two matrices gives another matrix right,

Comment: As you rightly pointed out b=x⊗y and c=y⊗x. Therefore, xy and yx are not the same.

Comment: Can you define this outer-product? An outer product of vectors gives a matrix, what are your vectors?